# Does hyphenation/syllabication hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, html, keywords

I have a header with a long keyword in it, which is ”pre-wrapped” per the designer's wish. Like so:

```
<h1>Prewrapped super-
ficial header</h1>
```

The css:

```
h1 {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Now suppose **superficial** was an important keyword. Will Google index it correctly, despite it being hyphenated and wrapped?

Comment: Good question, +1. I'm guessing it won't impact the SEO tremendously, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think your real heading does not contain hyphen and break line, it's your output that contain hyphen and break line, correct me if I am wrong? I mean do you really use hyphen in your heading?

Comment: @Goyllo It looks like the actual heading contains the hyphen and line break and they are using CSS to make sure that it displays that way.

Comment: As for Google, and likely Bing, this should not be a problem. It is not uncommon that terms are hyphenated. The page break is likely ignored. Semantically speaking, your example makes complete sense as a root and suffix which can still be understood as two terms. Even if this is not the case, Google should be testing word boundaries and will likely see that the hyphen should be ignored. Cheers!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Prewrapped+superficial+header%22&hl=en

Comment: "No results found"  -- I guess that answers the question

Comment: @Goyllo, yes, we really do use a hyphen in the heading.

Comment: As for searching google for the content, it is not launched yet. (And the heading in the OP is not the real heading.)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't cause any issues at all. Google is well versed in synonyms and can tell when one word should mean another. As a quick test using Google I did a search for `Super-ficial` and the results returned where for `superficial`. Should be all good.

Comment: The real test for this would be to search for superficial and then see if returns result for super-ficial. I guess, when we have launched the landing page I can do some tests like that.